# Changing .css background-color via jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

I have an issue when I want to change a background color of my div element via jquery after receiving an ajax respond, it doesn't work.(Code is validated, I tested it by entering a test line in error statement before changing css property and it worked.)
Here is the code:

```
#statusbox {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
display:inline-block;
float: left;
position:relative;
left:190px;
top:3px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;

border-color: black;
```

}

And the jquery

```
success: function(msg) {
    if (msg['connected']) {
        $('#statusbox').css("background-color", "#00FF00");
    } else $('#statusbox').css("background-color", "#FF0000");
},
error: function(error_msg) {
    $('#statusbox').css("background-color", "#00FF00");
}
```

Comment: you are missing a `#`

Comment: And you're missing an opening `{` after else. Please validate your code first before asking questions — sometimes it all boils down to a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have (had, in the original post) a tiny CSS syntax error:

`$.css({});` takes in an object containing properties as `CSS property => value`.

In you case, you are assigning `00FF00` to `background-color`, that would equal to the following CSS definition:

**CSS code**

```
#statusbox {
    background-color: 00FF00
}
```

You forgot the `#`, use:

**Javascript code**

```
$('#statusbox').css("background-color", "#00FF00");
```

---

Secondly, the first parameter of the success handler of `$.ajax()` is the HTML echoed by the script called.

That is, if your PHP script does this:

**PHP code**

```
echo 'connected';
```

You check that the following way:

**Javascript code**

```
success: function(msg) {
    if (msg == 'connected') {
        $('#statusbox').css("background-color", "#00FF00");
    } else $('#statusbox').css("background-color", "#FF0000");
}
```

Make sure you have no rogue whitespaces before or after the actual php code, because that will be echoed as well; or just strip the spaces:

**Javascript code**

```
success: function(msg) {
    if (msg.replace(' ', '') == 'connected') {
        $('#statusbox').css("background-color", "#00FF00");
    } else $('#statusbox').css("background-color", "#FF0000");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine in your code just use # before you colour code like below

```
$('#statusbox').css("background-color","#00FF00");}
```